# ios keyboardwillshow notification firing late

Tags: ios, notifications, keyboard

I am experiencing a strange error on iOS 8 when trying to synchronize an animation in tandem with the keyboard moving up after selecting a textfield. 
Specifically, I am trying to get the height of the keyboard in order to know how far up to move the text field by using the following code after registering for the keyboardwillshow notification:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
self.keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height;
[self moveToolbarUp];
}

-(void)moveToolbarUp
{
self.keyboardExpanded = YES;
CGRect frame = self.toolbar.frame;
DLog(@"keyboard height now:%f",self.keyboardHeight);
frame.origin.y = (self.view.frame.size.height-toolbarHeight-self.keyboardHeight);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
    self.toolbar.frame = frame;
}];
}
```

However, if I try to set a break point at the keyboardwillshow method, I can see that the keyboard is already all the way up when the method is called, and the animation is therefore delayed (the keyboard pops up and then a second or so later, the textfield follows). 
Has anybody else experienced this error? I am running on an iPhone 5s, iOS 8.0.2.

Thanks!!

Comment: Yea I'm facing the same issue. The keyboard is visible first and then selector for keyboardWillShow called. However, its happening for the first time only after my app launch.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error. The fact is that you can *remove* your `animateWithDuration` call. In iOS 8, `keyboardWillShow:` is called *inside the keyboard's animation*. You don't have to synchronize anything; anything you do will be part of the animation, automatically.

Comment: hmm I tried that however it's still not animating at the correct time. The entire keyboard will go all the way up and then the textfield follows a second or so after. Is it working correctly for you?

Comment: Yes but I'm a little unclear on what you're trying to do. "A second or so after" sounds a little long, but in, say, a text field or a scroll view, it is normal for it to scroll just after the keyboard has finished animating into place. I don't see that as objectionable. This project shows a typical strategy: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch10p522textFieldScrollView/ch23p805textFieldSliding/ViewController.swift